# Read data from files on server and update content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Sorry I am not experienced in coding..

I use the scrolling of the page to get a value from document.body.scrollTop when there is an window.onscroll event in javascript. There is a div with display=block, of height 60000.
My content is in a div with fixed position so always stays at the center of the window.

I have a dozen text files on the server, each 60000 lines, each line can be around 60 characters long. These lines gives data for what is to happen in the fixed div content.

My goal is to update my content (with javascript) according to the scroll value so according to the files lines data.

I found out how to get a single line as an array (tabs used) from a file at each request, in php, and it seems fast.

```
function readEvent($Dname,$Dvalue) {
    $myobject = 'timelines/'.$Dname.'.txt';
    $ThisOne = new SplFileObject($myobject);
    $ThisOne->seek($Dvalue-1);
    $myResult = explode("\t", $ThisOne->current());
    return $myResult; 
}
```

The Dvalue should be document.body.scrollTop, so in javascript I have

```
window.onscroll = function() {timelineUpdate()};
function timelineUpdate() {
    console.log(document.body.scrollTop);
    var Devent = $readEvent(myDname,document.body.scrollTop);
}
```

Of course I can't do this, calling the php function readEvent from Javascript, passing parameters to it and getting the result.
So how do I do this, I can't find the way.
Or maybe I do it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

It happens via an ajax call, go through this article. http://fatfolderdesign.com/173/content-load-on-scroll-with-jquery

Instead of JS, Use Jquery (Use jquery supports / take care of all mobile compatibility issues) and do a ajax call. You need to pass the file and the current start value.  And in your php script need to get the parameters and read the content using the PHP function you mentioned.

i.e.. $file = $_GET['filename']; $pos = $_GET['pos'];

<?php echo readEvent($file, $pos); ?>

Comment: I am still lost despite trying and searching other posts. I can't figure out how to call my php function with the filename and position parameters, from Javascript, and get the result back in javascript...

Comment: See the working example here http://fatfolderdesign.com/ex/scroll_load/

Comment: does this example actually reload the page?

Comment: it sends a ajax call. Ajax sends a background call in browser, which user is not aware and load the contents more interactively.